# How to visualise the progress of data writing in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I use `scan_csv` + `sink_parquet` when combining multiple CSVs into a single parquet file using the Lazy method.

I was previously using `read_csv` + `write_parquet` and when visualising the progress of writing data I was using `tqdm`, but when using `scan_csv` + `sink_parquet`, `tqdm` doesn't work because `scan_csv` completes instantly.

Can you tell me how to use `scan_csv` + `sink_parquet` and how to view the progress of the data being written?

Comment: You can't, at least, not directly. You have to settle for watching the file(s) get bigger in the os and guessing how how big they'll be eventually.